# How to print out all combinations?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int day[30],
    month[11],
    year[2] = { 2000, 2001 };
int combinations[743];

printf("Days:\n");

for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
{
    day[i - 1] = i;
    printf("%d ", day[i-1]);
}

printf("\n\nMonth:\n");

for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
{
    month[j - 1] = j;
    printf("%d ", day[j - 1]);
}

printf("\n\nYear:\n%d %d\n\n", year[0], year[1]);

for (int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, k = 0;
    x <= 30, y <= 11, z <= 1, k <= 743;
    x++, y++, z++, k++)
{
    if (x == 31)
    {
        x = 0;
    }

    if (y == 11)
    {
        y = 0;
    }

    combinations[k] = day[x],".",month[y],".",year[0];
}

for (int a = 0; a <= 20; a++)
{
    printf("Combination: %d \n", combinations[a]);
}

getch();}
```

I want to make a program that prints out all combinations for birthdays for 2000,2001 people, but I get something weird in the output

It looks like this:

Days:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31

Month:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

Year:
2000 2001

Combination: 1
Combination: 2
Combination: 3
Combination: 4
Combination: 5
Combination: 6
Combination: 7
Combination: 8
Combination: 9
Combination: 10
Combination: 11
Combination: 12
Combination: 13
Combination: 14
Combination: 15
Combination: 16
Combination: 17
Combination: 18
Combination: 19
Combination: 20
Combination: 21

Comment: what `combinations[k] = day[x],".",month[y],".",year[0];` is supposed to do? btw, `day[30]` should be `day[31]`

Comment: its supposed to do "01.01.2000 ..... 31.12.2001"

Comment: combinations array is `int`, and you're trying to convert ints to string and concatenate them, it is not how it works in c

Comment: `,` is a comma operator, it works similar to `;`. In this case `combinations[k] = day[x],".",month[y],".",year[0];` is just `combinations[k] = day[x]; "."; month[y]; "."; year[0];` which is just `combinations[k] = day[x];`. C is not php.

Comment: any ideas how to fix it ? when I do day[x] + "." + month[y] + "." + ...  ; it says it cant add pointers :(

Comment: There is much work needed. You want a string? You need to convert all integers into a string, concatenate that with your custom parts, probably you will go for `snprintf` and declare `combinations` as an array of arrays of characters (an array of strings) or an array of pointers to characters and handle dynamic memory allocation and dealocation. An advice would be to grab a good C book and learn about strings in C.

Comment: You have undefined behavior in your program when accessing day and month in the loop. `day` is declared as `int[30]` so it has 30 elements, not 31. The indexing start from zero, so the max index is 29. Yet in the loop for `(int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
{
    day[i - 1] = i;` once `i = 31` then `day[30] = 31`, which is accesses the memory out of bound

Comment: can you please tell me how to start to snprintf ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a learning site..... You can pretty much find everything on the net, including [documenatation](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3p-snprintf/) and [cool tutorials](http://joequery.me/code/snprintf-c/). Just google `snprintf tutorial` and such...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

//changed days to 31 and months to 12

int day[31],
    month[12],
    year[2] = { 2000, 2001 };

//made three arrays one for days,one for months,one for year storage, or you can use structure array, structure should have three fields
int combinations1[744];
int combinations2[744];
int combinations3[744];

printf("Days:\n");


for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
{
    day[i - 1] = i;
    printf("%d ", day[i-1]);
}

printf("\n\nMonth:\n");

for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
{
    month[j - 1] = j;
    printf("%d ", day[j - 1]);
}

printf("\n\nYear:\n%d %d\n\n", year[0], year[1]);

int x,y,z,k=0;

//this will be code for storing all combination of days, looping through all days of a month of a year, then to next month and finally to next year

for(x = 0; x < 2 ; x ++)
{
    for(y = 0; y < 12; y ++)
    {
        for(z = 0; z < 31; z++)
    {   
    combinations1[k]=z+1;
    combinations2[k]=y+1;
    combinations3[k]=year[x];   
k++;
}
}
}

// printing all combinations

for (int a = 0; a < 744; a++)
{
    printf("Combination: %d.%d.%d\n", combinations1[a],combinations2[a],combinations3[a]);
}

//getch();
}
```

I have explained the code in comments. Please read the comments to understand

Comment: please provide an explanation for your answer.  only having a code block will not suffice for most users.

Comment: Yesss ! It works, thanks man, I will try to understand this code :) it s greatly appericated

Comment: @Tau you should have seen the code, i have explained the code in comments

Comment: apologies, i had only glanced at your post when i posted the previous comment.

Comment: but how to save it to file `FILE *f = fopen("all_dates.txt", "w");
 for (int a = 0; a < 744; a++)
 {
  fwrite("Combination: %d.%d.%d\n", combinations1[a], combinations2[a], combinations3[a], f);
 }` this doesnt work...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, quick mistakes there:

- In the second for-cycle you are printing the day array, the only reason the outut there is correct is because the numbers are the same and the cycle stop at 12. Anyways, you should fix that, for the sake of good programing.
- The last cyle shouldnt be done like that, you are literally asking for bugs. Divide that cycle to 3 different ones. The outside cycle is the year, it will be executed twice (2000, 2001), the inner cycle will iterate 12 times( that will be the month) and the last one will iterate 31 times (that will be the days)

Doing it like this, makes it much easier to read and to do it right, since in your code that cycle will only be executed twice, since Z stops at 2 and you increase it every iteration.

```
for(year = 0; year < 2 ; year ++)
    for(month = 0; month < 12; month ++)
        for(day = 0; day < 31; day++)
            //combination code goes here
```

Last things, if you want to save the date you cant make it like an int, unless you sum the days and use it as a reference, if you want something like "11-05-2000" you either creat a struct for that or save it as string. Second you are assuming 31 for every month...

Any further question, as you may have, feel free to ask :)

Comment: I want to save it as a string, do I have to convert it to char ?

Comment: No you dont xD It's much easier to simply do a struct with 3 fields(year, month and  day). You make an array of that and in each iteration of the inner cycle (where i wrote "combination code goes here") you set each field with the day,month,year values which are the index of the cycles.

Comment: @СтепанБандера keep in mind that what we call a "string" is actually a `char*`

Comment: aren`t structs kinda OOP ?

Comment: No, a class and a struct are two entirely diferent things. Can look kinda similar at a first glance, but dont mix things up!